# Third Maximum Number in Leetcode-javaScript

Tags: javascript

Given an integer array nums, return the third distinct maximum number in this array. If the third maximum does not exist, return the maximum number.
Input: nums = [2,2,3,1]
Output: 1

my code:

```
var thirdMax = function(nums) {
     let tempArr =new Set(nums.sort((a,b) => b-a));
     let newArr = Array.from(tempArr);

  return newArr[2];
  
};
```

In console it works, but return undefined.
May I ask what I'm missing here?
Thank you.

Comment: What is `slice()` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Your code works so long as there are 3 distinct numbers. You will get "undefined" if there are less because you don't handle this requirement: *If the third maximum does not exist, return the maximum number*, and thus index `2` will be out of bounds.

Comment: you are right. Slice do nothing and I forgot to delete since we are using new Set here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May I ask what I'm missing here?

You are missing this part of the challenge:

> If the third maximum does not exist, return the maximum number

Your code is looking for a third entry that might not exist (hence `undefined`). You'll need to test your code with input that only has 2 or 1 unique value(s), and adapt your code accordingly.

If you can't find how to do that, here is the spoiler:

> `return newArr[2] ?? newArr[0];`

Note that `slice` expects a numeric argument (not a string). You can just omit that argument.